# How do I make one-to-many chat with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I can achieve one-to-one chat now, and want to make it one-to-many: a broadcaster with N viewer. "How many viewer I have, how many PeerConnection I will create in broadcaster"  Is that right ？

Comment: This might be a better candidate for a Google search, since you are looking for an easily found code-sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating multi peer connection will work. But if you want to implement a group chat, implement a proper message flow through your own server or you can use firebase for that.

Creating multiple connection  will only give you live chat but implementing it through your own server you can get features like :

1. Storing history of chat
2. offline chat
3. etc

Answer (score 0):

To shift from 1:1 interaction to broadcast with WebRTC (or any video related tech), you will need a media server that will forward the media to whoever you want.

The reason for that is that the amount of media being sent is such that cannot be handled by most consumer network connections - and when it can, you are taxing your browser's resources to the extreme.

Look at Kurento, Jitsi and Janus for open source alternatives that enable you to do that.

You can learn more about [server side in WebRTC](https://bloggeek.me/webrtcs-server-side-enroll/) here